# Kendo comboBox editor with nested grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I tried to add comboBox editor template in child kendo grid (nested grid), but When I open the page an error returns says "Invalid template".

What is the correct way to add combo box Editor template in the child grid

Here is my Editor Template code

```
@( Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
            .DataTextField("OriginText")
            .DataValueField("OriginID")
                .Name("OriginID")
    .Filter("contains")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("Origin_Combo", "ItemOrigin");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    }))
```

And this is a part of my grid

```
.Name("ItemOrigin_#=ItemSuppliersID#")
.
.
columns.Bound(p => p.Origin.OriginNameE")
      .EditorTemplateName("OriginComboEditor")

    .IncludeInMenu(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The EditorTemplate ComboBox:  Name("OriginID") should match the Grid column's name :"columns.Bound(p => p.Origin.OriginNameE")

So. you else change EditorTemplate name to Origin.OriginNameE or setup the Grid model a new name for this column.